# Configure Nginx server on home network

Tags: networking, router, nginx, ubuntu-20.04

I'm setting up an Nginx web server on Ubuntu on my home network. I can access it from any device on the network using thet 192.168.x.x IP address.

Now I want to make it publically available as well. I configured port forwarding on my router. I assume that I should be able to access the web server using my public IP address. Is that a correct assumption? When I enter it into a browser, I get "this site cannot be reached". I don't get the expected page.

How do I troubleshoot this? My first thought is to look at the nginx configuration file. I can do more reading on it. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Compare the reported public IP (e.g. [Google "What is my IP](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip)) to any public IP reported by the router under its settings. If they are different (e.g. your external public IP is `1.2.3.4` but your router states it is `10.0.0.1`), you may have an ISP that uses [CGNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) that would interfere with what you're attempting to achieve. If this isn't the case, I would suggest double-checking your port forwarding, PC firewall and server settings (e.g. are you operating on the correct port?).

Comment: @Anaksunaman Your first tip appears to be the situation..."What is my IP" (which is what I was using) shows a different IP than my router settings.

Comment: *"Your first tip appears to be the situation"* - Then you essentially have two choices. Contact your ISP and allow them to set you up with a static IP that can be accessed directly or use a third-party server to "relay" incoming requests to your local server. There are services such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) that can do this for you or (theoretically) you could get e.g. a virtual private server (VPS) and set this up yourself with the right tools.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thanks for the tips. I'd prefer to see what I can do directly through my ISP, so I'll try that first. Otherwise I'll look into ngrok.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck. =)

Comment: @Anaksunaman Called my ISP an they did something. Now it works.

Comment: I am genuinely glad to hear that. =)